# list_display. How to display value from choices?

Tags: django, django-admin

```
STATUS = (
    (1, "Sent"),
    (2, "Not send",),)

class Log(models.Model):
        status = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=STATUS)
```

admin

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['status']
```

This display:

> Status - (leer)

How to display Status - Sent or Not send here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

simply use:

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['get_status_display']
```

[Django documentation: get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Answer (score 11):

(Updated to django 1.8)
the best is to create a function

```
def get_status(self, obj):
    return obj.get_status_display()

get_status.short_description = 'Status'
```

Put 'get_status' in your list_display and *Status* it will be the column name in the admin list.

Comment: In django 1.8 i had to use the following code in my admin.py:

`def get_status(self, obj):
    return obj.get_status_display()`